# Django Javascript Explanation

Tags: javascript, django

I have this code and I'm trying to make sense of it - I'm not really sure how it works-

```
{% if book %}

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.get('/ajax/book/{{ book.id }}/timetable/', {}, function(data) {

                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var events = new Array();
                for (var i in data) {
                    events.push({
                        id: data[i].id,
                        title: '{{ request.user.name }}',
                        start: Date.parse(data[i].startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                        end: Date.parse(data[i].endTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                        allDay: false
                    });
                }

                var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek'
                    },
                    theme: true,
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,
                    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    },
                    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                        var title = '{{ request.user.name }}';
                        $.post('/ajax/book/{{ book.id }}/timetable/new/', {
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
                            startTime: start.format("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"),
                            endTime: end.format("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"),
                        }, function(data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay
                                },
                                true // make the event "stick"
                            );
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    events: events,
                    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
                        alert(
                            "The end date of " + event.title + " has been moved " +
                            dayDelta + " days and " +
                            minuteDelta + " minutes."
                        );

                        if (!confirm("Is this okay?")) {
                            revertFunc();
                        }

                    }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>
```

From what I can tell, ajax/book/.../timetable and ajax/book/.../timetable/new call book_timetable(request,id) and book_timetable_new(request,id)-

```
  url(r'^ajax/book/(?P<bookid>\d+)/timetable/$', twobooks.ajax.views.book_timetable),
    url(r'^ajax/book/(?P<bookid>\d+)/timetable/new/$', twobooks.ajax.views.book_timetable_new),
```

where the functions are -

```
def book_timetable(request, bookid):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=bookid)
    rawslots = TimeSlot.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(book=book)
    slots = []
    for rawslot in rawslots:
        slot = {
            'id':           rawslot.id,
            'startTime':    str(rawslot.startTime),
            'endTime':      str(rawslot.endTime),
        }
        slots.append(slot)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(slots))

def book_timetable_new(request, bookid):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=bookid)
    startTime = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startTime'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    endTime = datetime.strptime(request.POST['endTime'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    timeslot = TimeSlot(
        user = request.user,
        book = book,
        startTime = startTime,
        endTime = endTime,
    )
    timeslot.save()
    return JSONify("")
```

I'm trying to do something similar to this, except with other data, which is why I'm trying to get how this works. If anyone could explain it to me it'd be great!

Comment: What are you not understanding? The JS, the Python, what?

Comment: Well I understand generally what's happening, in that I'm getting the array of timeSlots through the get request and then presenting them in the calendar. However, I don't understand how the template is being called, and how to present say, all of the timeslots of a user (across all books)

Comment: in effect, I'm not sure how the JS and the python are talking, further, I'm not sure what the JS is doing (although I'm not sure that I need to know for the task I've stipulated)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly standard AJAX pattern. The template is rendered by the original view, as normal. In the course of rendering, some elements of the Javascript which are marked as Django template variables are filled in - eg `{{ book.id }}` and `{{ request.user.name }}` - so that by the time it gets to the browser, those are indistinguishable from the rest of the JS.

Now, the Javascript makes a call to the server, passing those elements. The server responds with JSON data, which is parsed by the function which is the third parameter to the `.get` call. I haven't looked too deeply into that function, but it seems to be using that data to instantiate a `fullCalendar`, which is presumably a separate jQuery script.

One slightly strange thing is that the AJAX call is set to run as soon as the browser has loaded the page - normally there's no point doing that, since you could simply include the data in the original template. Usually AJAX is set to execute in response to some event in the browser, such as a button click.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the template is rendered in the original view - I can't see this happening? 

Also, do I need the select:function(start,end,allDay) in order to display hte calendar?

Comment: It's not either of those views you refer to: there is a separate **non-Ajax** view that is responsible for originally rendering the template, when the user goes to the page in their browser. As for the `select` function, you would have to look at the documentation for `fullCalendar`: I expect it's a function that is triggered when you select a day in the calendar, so if you want something to happen in that circumstance, you will need the function.